# re-organise a result array from db-query in codeignitter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a array of results from a database query.

Now, i need the array in a little bit other structure as it comes from the database query.

I do this for the moment.

```
$this->db->where($where);
$all=$this->db->get('my_table')->result_array();
```

after that i reorganize in this way

```
foreach($all as $element)
{
    foreach($element as $subkey=>$subelement)
    {
        $preset_templates[$element['emailtemplateid']][$subkey]=$subelement;
    }               
}
```

Is there a easier or shorter way to do the same?

Comment: i don't get what u r doing here... what happens if you have more elements with the same `emailtemplateid` ?

Comment: it's unique :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try below given code.

```
foreach($all as $element=>$subelement)
   {
     $preset_templates[$subelement['emailtemplateid']]=$subelement;
   }
```

I hope it helps.